# Export wizard error for exiting excel files in sas 9.2

Tags: sas, excel-2016

I recently upgraded Excel 2007 to 2016, But SAS export wizard does not work after that.
The error messages in log is as follows:

> Error: libname is not assigned
>
> Error: class: not registered

It's not Syntax errors in editor but export wizard problem.
I wonder if it need to any special setting for excel 2016 or not.
But does SAS support the 2016 version?

Comment: SAS9.2 likely won't support 2016, it's not a supported version.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, your Office 2016 is 64 bit and SAS 9.2 is 32 bit. That means you can't use `PROC EXPORT` or `LIBNAME` access with `DBMS=EXCEL`, or the export wizard from base SAS.

The export wizard from Enterprise Guide will still work, as will the `xls` engine.

In order to fix this, upgrade to SAS 9.4 (64 bit) or downgrade to a 32 bit version of Office.

Comment: My Office 2016 is 32bit but OS is 64bit. 
Is this a problem when using the program?

Comment: Not necessarily no.